# Transaction does not work in django

Tags: django, transactions

I want to use transaction in my django project,so I build a view to practice

code in views.py:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def test(request):
    import random
    wiki = Entry.objects.get(id=854)
    wiki.title = 'title-{}'.format(random.randrange(1,100))
    wiki.save()
    transaction.rollback()
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

As you see,I updated the `wiki.title` and then I rollback it,so,in my opinion，the `wiki.title` will not be updated to database,but in fact is not,I don't know why.

My enviroment is django 1.4.2,python 2.7, mysql 5.6.13

the doc:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: And did you choose a table engine that supports transactions?

Comment: Thanks for you remind.I used the default table engine MyISAM which does not support transactions.I have changed it to Innodb,the problem is resolved,thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call `transaction.commit()` explicitly when you decorate a view with `@transaction.commit_manually`, see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually